# With Bubble, how to extract JSON's value to Text

Tags: json

[image]

Now, I do not know how to extract JSON-style data into the Bubble UI (Text).

Current steps below

1. Push the button "RUN dexi.io API"
2. From the API above, a Json file is gotten.
3. This is where I got stuck. From this JSON below, I want to extract Headline's value from "rows" and paste each of them to Text UI (in the picture, these are red-highlighted)

*Here is a gotten JSON data

```
{
    "headers": [
        "Headline",
        "URL",
        "error"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            "Sompo Japan to Name Veep Ishikawa as Pres.",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024012000369",
            null
        ],
        [
            "Fujitsu Knew about Faulty System from Start: Senior Official",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024012000361",
            null
        ],
        [
            "AWS to Invest 15 B. Dollars to Develop Data Centers in Japan",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011901007",
            null
        ],
        [
            "Fujitsu Positive about Compensation over U.K. Post Office Scandal",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011900298",
            null
        ],
        [
            "Japan's Sekisui House to Buy U.S. Home Builder",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011801230",
            null
        ],
        [
            "No Full Recovery Prospect for Mobile Networks in Noto Quake-Hit Areas",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011801201",
            null
        ],
        [
            "TSMC to Start Chip Mass Production in Kumamoto Late 2024",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011801175",
            null
        ],
        [
            "JR East to Promote Kise to CEO",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011800275",
            null
        ],
        [
            "Daihatsu to Mull Recalling 2 Models over Test Fraud",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011701016",
            null
        ],
        [
            "(Update) JAL to Promote Exec Tottori to Pres.",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011701046",
            null
        ],
        [
            "JAL to Promote Exec Tottori to Pres.",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011700886",
            null
        ],
        [
            "Fujitsu CEO Apologizes over British Post Scandal",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011700290",
            null
        ],
        [
            "Nippon Yusen Suspends Transits in Red Sea",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011700288",
            null
        ],
        [
            "Sompo Holdings Blamed for Flawed Supervision over Bigmotor",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011601081",
            null
        ],
        [
            "Daihatsu to Lose Certificates for 3 Models over Test Fraud",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011600501",
            null
        ],
        [
            "Toyota Plans Global Output of 10.3 M. Units in 2024",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011501154",
            null
        ],
        [
            "JAL Unveils New Flagship Aircraft with \"Private Suites\"",
            "/jc/eng?g=ind&k=2024011500914",
            null
        ]
    ],
    "totalRows": 17
}
```

Please give an idea to deal with how to extract JSON values.